# How to show lambda function return values in Outputs of Cloudformation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am looking for an option to list results of AWS::Lambda::Function in Outputs of Cloudformation.

Following is the snippet of cloudformation template for AWS:Lambda::Function

```
Resources:
 AthenaLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    DependsOn:
      - IamRoleLambdaForAthena
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          import botocore
          import os 
          ath = boto3.client('athena')
          def handler(event, context):
              outputBucket = os.environ.get("outputBucket")
              QSTRING = 'select * from tableName limit 10'
              response = ath.start_query_execution(QueryString=str(QSTRING), ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': outputBucket})
              s3BucketOut = output_bucket + response['ResponseMetadata']['RequestId']
              return s3BucketOut
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      MemorySize: 128
      Role: !GetAtt IamRoleLambdaForAthena.Arn
      Timeout: 30
      Environment:
        Variables:
          outputBucket: !Ref OutputS3Bucket
```

I want to show the value retuned by lambda function  `s3BucketOut` in Outputs of Cloudformation. Something like below (off course, the code below doesn't work).

```
Outputs:
  LambdaFunctionOutput:
    Value: !Ref AthenaLambdaFunction.s3BucketOut
    Description: Return Value of Lambda Function
```

Any suggestions please. TIA

Answer (score 4):

You are half-way through it. With your code, you created the AWS Lambda function that you want to run. Now you need to make this function run on CloudFormation and capture its value. Note that you need to make small changes on your code to allow the value to be captured by CloudFormation.

The full code will be similar to this:

```yaml
Resources:
  AthenaLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    DependsOn:
      - IamRoleLambdaForAthena
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          import botocore
          import os
          import cfnresponse # this needs to be imported for replying to CloudFormation
          ath = boto3.client('athena')
          def handler(event, context):
              outputBucket = os.environ.get("outputBucket")
              QSTRING = 'select * from tableName limit 10'
              response = ath.start_query_execution(QueryString=str(QSTRING), ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': outputBucket})
              s3BucketOut = output_bucket + response['ResponseMetadata']['RequestId']
              responseData = {} # added
              responseData['S3BucketOut'] = s3BucketOut # added
              cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData) # return modified
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      MemorySize: 128
      Role: !GetAtt IamRoleLambdaForAthena.Arn
      Timeout: 30
      Environment:
        Variables:
          outputBucket: !Ref OutputS3Bucket

  S3BucketOutInvocation:
    Type: Custom::S3BucketOut
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt AthenaLambdaFunction.Arn
      Region: !Ref "AWS::Region"

Outputs:
  LambdaFunctionOutput: 
    Value: !GetAtt S3BucketOutInvocation.S3BucketOut
    Description: Return Value of Lambda Function
```

---

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html

Comment: This is not working because of this error `Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [S3BucketOut] in the Resources block of the template`.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create what is called a "Lambda-backed Custom Resource" You would use this during Stack creation to get bits of information at creation type.

Further information can be found here

[AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html)